# IntelliJ is not auto loading packages for Scala

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ and Scala programming. I am trying to write Scala program for which I have imported package "org.apache.spark._" but it is always highlighted.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYdMG.png)

Error: object apache is not a member of package org
 import org.apache.spark._

When I check google, I see something like adding to sbt.build file. I doubt that is correct. I am assuming IntelliJ should be able to auto load anything it need and discard that are not needed.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: you need to define dependencies in sbt or POM file..

Comment: org.apache.spark. is the external library either you have to add it to external libraries of a project or use any build tool like sbt. you need to read about sbt